# Upload multiple images in django

Tags: django

I have models like:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)



class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='image_in_gallery')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/%Y/%m/%d')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How can I upload multiple images to Gallery, I mean using forms.

Comment: Use `InlineFormSet` for `GalleryImage` model. Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: you mean something like this?: http://whoisnicoleharris.com/assets/img/formset-animation.gif

Comment: Yes you can display forms dynamically using javascript.

Comment: What's if I have 100 images to upload?

Comment: You can add forms in batches of 10 or 20. Then after every batch of extra forms are filled you can submit the form and load more extra forms for the next batch.

Comment: You could also use Django Rest Framework and make a serializer of `GalleryImage` model and use it for dynamically adding images.

Comment: anyway it is possible to upload using one form?

Comment: I was watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9MDtQHwGYM

Comment: Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files . It is based on the video but a more cleaner approach. But with this method you wont be able to put title in the object of `GalleryImage` model.